# About the slack variable for hinge-loss SVM

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

The hinge-loss SVM is defined
$$
\min_{w,b} \frac{1}{2}w^T w+\sum_{i=1}^{N}\max\{0,1-y_i(w^Tx_i +b)\}
$$
By introducing a slack variable $\xi_i$, the optimization problem is changed to
$$
\min_{w,b,\xi_i} \frac{1}{2}w^Tw+\sum_{i=1}^{N}\xi_i \\
\xi_i\geq 0 \\
\xi_i\geq 1-y_i(w^Tx_i +b)
$$

But why this is right? My understanding on this is
$$
\xi_i=\max\{0,1-y_i(w^Tx_i+b)\}
$$
then, we just get
$$
1-y_i(w^Tx_i+b)>0 \Rightarrow \xi_i=1-y_i(w^Tx_i+b) \\
1-y_i(w^Tx_i+b)=0 \Rightarrow \xi_i=0 \\
1-y_i(w^Tx_i+b)<0 \Rightarrow \xi_i=0
$$
So, how could we achieve the inequality $~\xi_i\geq 1-y_i(w^Tx_i +b)~$? Is there any theorem on this? Does a slack variable need to do so?

What's wrong with my understanding? Please help check it.

**UPDATE:**

I just found the truth:
$$
1-y_i(w^Tx_i+b)=0 \Rightarrow \xi_i=0 \\
1-y_i(w^Tx_i+b)<0 \Rightarrow \xi_i=0
$$
leads to
$$
1-y_i(w^Tx_i+b)=\xi_i \Leftarrow \xi_i=0 \\
1-y_i(w^Tx_i+b)<\xi_i \Leftarrow \xi_i=0
$$
then, we have
$$
1-y_i(w^Tx_i+b)\leq\xi_i  
$$

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking. You yourself are showing that if $1-y_i(w^Tx_i+b)$ is positive, then that is the value that $\xi_i$ achieves; otherwise, $\xi_i=0$. And that's what the slack variable version does, too. That's exactly what you want.

Comment: @MichaelGrant, yes, I've realized that. I should replace thr $0$ with the $\xi_i=0$. Then, the $\xi_i\geq 1-y_i(w^Tx_i+b)$. Thank you! At that time I didn't found this relation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm glad you found your answer. For archival purposes I think it would be good to derive the equivalence in a couple of steps, though.

At first, you might be tempted to introduce $\xi_i$ by transforming your model from this
$$\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize}_{w,b} & \frac{1}{2}w^T w+\sum_{i=1}^{N}\max\{0,1-y_i(w^Tx_i +b)\}
\end{array}$$
to this:
$$\begin{array}{lll}
\text{minimize}_{w,b,\xi} & \frac{1}{2}w^T w+\sum_{i=1}^{N}\xi_i \\
\text{subject to}         & \max\{0,1-y_i(w^Tx_i +b)\} = \xi_i, & i=1,2,\dots,N
\end{array}$$
This is indeed equivalent, but you've also broken convexity. It turns out that what you *really* want to do is transform your model *this* way instead:
$$\begin{array}{lll}
\text{minimize}_{w,b,\xi} & \frac{1}{2}w^T w+\sum_{i=1}^{N}\xi_i \\
\text{subject to}         & \max\{0,1-y_i(w^Tx_i +b)\} \leq \xi_i, & i=1,2,\dots,N
\end{array}$$
Now we still have convexity; but do we have equivalence?

Yes! And the reason why is that those inequalities must be *active* at the optimum. that is,
$$(w^*,b^*,\xi^*)\text{ optimum} \quad\Longrightarrow\quad \max\{0,1-y_i((w^*)^Tx_i+b^*)\}=\xi^*_i, ~i=1,2\dots,N.$$
Suppose this isn't the case: suppose that, for a particular $j\in{1,2,\dots,N}$, we have
$$\max\{0,1-y_i((w^*)^Tx_j+b^*)\}<\xi^*_j.$$
Then we can just reduce $\xi^*_j$ from its current value
to $\bar{\xi}_j = \max\{0,1-y_i(w^Tx_j+b)\}$ without violating the inequality; and this
will reduce the objective as well! This contradicts the claim that the original $\xi^*$ was optimal.

Now that we've taken this step, we can simply take advantage of the fact that
$$\max\{a,b\}\leq c \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad a \leq c,~b\leq c$$
for any real $a,b,c$. This allows us to replace those individual inequalities with
$$\begin{array}{lll}
\text{minimize}_{w,b,\xi} & \frac{1}{2}w^T w+\sum_{i=1}^{N}\xi_i \\
\text{subject to}         & 0 \leq \xi_i, ~ i=1,2,\dots,N \\
& 1-y_i(w^Tx_i +b) \leq \xi_i, ~ i=1,2,\dots, N
\end{array}$$
And we've arrived at the result.

Comment: Hi, Michael, thank you very much for detail explanation. But I'm not sure why the formula $\max\{0,1-y_i(w^Tx_i+b)\}=\xi_i$ would broke convexity. Should the introduced slack variable $\xi_i$ keep the problem convex?

Comment: Nonlinear equations are almost always non-convex. The exceptions are rare and contrived and never allowed in practice. Using the inequality form instead preserves convexity, because the max function is convex.